# Ajax + JSF 2 times clicking after the first click

Tags: javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have a dataTable with a column named DELETE (it is a link) which has an listener . When I click it the first time (click 1) it deletes the row (as expected), but when I try it with another row after that nothing happened (click 2). In fact wherever I click next nothing happen. I should click another time (click 3) to get it work. I don't want that.

Attention: The "delete()" method in my_user is not reached after "click 2".

Here is the code for the column:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">#{lng.del}</f:facet>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{my_user.delete}" render="@all" />
            <h:graphicImage name="delete.png" library="images" styleClass="tableIcon" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've multiple forms inside the table. When you re-render *another* form from inside a form by ajax, then its view state will get lost and hence the 1st click will fail. This click however takes care that the form gets the view state back, so the 2nd click works.

Technically you need to re-render only the content of the other form, but this isn't possible in this particular use case. Better put the `<h:form>` outside the `<h:dataTable>` so that you have a single form with a shared view state.

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable>
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

If your page contains another forms as well, I'd suggest to render only the current form instead of all, otherwise any actions on those forms will fail as well.

```
<f:ajax event="click" listener="#{my_user.delete}" render="@form" />
```

Comment: Thnks for the explanation. Very useful!

Comment: It worked perfectly until I added onevent="confirmRemoving()" to the <f:ajax ... />. Where the function is: 

function confirmRemoving() {
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?');
}

The same thing happened. Need 2 click next time I try to delete.
What do you think happens now?

Comment: Hm.. that's strange. When I add onClick to the commandLink -  <h:commandLink onclick="return confirm('Blah')" > ... </h:commandLink>
it works.

Comment: Isn't it the same as plain javascript? For example: 
event="click" onevent="function()" is like onclick="function()" ?

Comment: No, definitely not. You want `onclick`. The `<f:ajax onevent>` is called 3 times during Ajax request lifecycle. It provides a hook on the begin, success and complete events of the Ajax request lifecycle. For example, to show and hide a progress bar or to report Ajax status. Please do not confuse it with `onclick` of the component. I strongly suggest to learn some basic HTML/JS before continuing with JSF.